# Printing content of WebBrowser Control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I want to print data present in Webbrowser Control. My data is loaded from datatable which contains HTML formatted text. When I tried to print it with RichTextBox it was not able to recognize HTML controls and was not able to render.

But when I tried to print using webbrowser control, noting gets printed. How to achieve this.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("WAIVER_TERMS");
webBrowser1.Print()
```

Comment: If everything can be displayed in one unscrollable window, why not try Control.ToImage()?

Comment: @Daniel: Although Content at my screen is dynamic so cant be created as image for printing and I think this would not be a good way. Not sure about it althoug

Comment: Content has to be static at one time - every control on windows forms has an ability to render itself to the bitmap - then you just print that bitmap or include it in some other document...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try `IWebBrowser2.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT)`? It should work, I've used succesully many time.

Comment: pls elaborate it a bit.